# Render React components based on data from Python/Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, mongodb, flask, content-management-system

I'm trying my hand at building a simple CMS with React, Flask, and MongoDB. I am trying to find a way to get data from MongoDB through Flask to render the correct React components.

The data is stored in MongoDB as:

```
{
    title: "home",
    modules: {
        headerBlock: {
            title: "My Website"
            byline: "Some other text here"
        }
    }
}
```

I can get that data into Python fairly easily, but then I need to get Flask to render the React components. It would translate to:

```
<Header title="My Website" byline="Some other text here" />
```

So there needs to be some way for Flask to provide a container *and* information about which components to render. (There will be more than one component).

Any help or tips or pushes in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: I hope that you are not injecting react component into flask html templates. If you tend to use react, you should use something like axios to make api call and then have flask render server response in json. its very easy. You should also get ready to learn json web token as session login will not work for SPA

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you are trying to build a single page application SPA , with react in front end, you would need to pass data from your back-end (flask) to react as json data. 
Flask has a function called jsonify that reponse to json.